# Angular 2 - Translate string with other string to translate as it's param

Tags: angular

I want to display a translated title, like:  `"Status of my dog"`

I want to translate `"Status of my {{param}}"` and `"dog"` independently, because maybe in some language it should be displayed as `"My dog status"` (order changed).

I achived it by doing two separate translations - one in html and one in ts:

html:

```
{{'TITLE' | translate: {param: getParam()} }}
```

ts:

```
getParam(): string {
  return this.translateService.instant(this.param.name); // where param = {name: 'DOG'}
}
```

and the translation strings are (example for english):

```
"TITLE": "Status of my {{param}}"
"DOG": "dog"
```

It works fine, but I was wondering - is it maybe doable by doing only translation in html file, with maybe some additional things in `translate`?

Like...

```
{{'TITLE' | translate: {param: param.name | translate} }}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like I should try the intuitive solution before postion a question.

The answer is just like I guessed above:

```
{{'TITLE' | translate: {param: param.name | translate} }}
```